# Return character at the specified string position

Tags: vb6

I'm looking for a function in Visual Basic 6 that will allow me to specify a position in a string and then return the character in that position.

To clarify let's say I have the string "541". The character in position 2 (or maybe pos 2 is pos 1 in reality?) is "4". I want that value to be returned.

I've tried out Mid(), Left() and Right() but did not find a way to get it to return the middle character.

Hopefully my explanation is sufficient for you to get the point. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's `Mid(string, start position, length)`, such as `Mid("541", 2, 1)`

Comment: It is worth noting that `Mid()` returns a Variant and `Mid$()` returns a String.  The main issue is performance, Variants being slower to work with.

Comment: +1. @Riketh, you might be interested to read the manual? [`Mid` topic is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445073(v=vs.60).aspx)